# InvalidCastException in custom JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonconverter

I am attempting to create a null safe json converter that handles json string values like "null" and return a default instance of a type.

So far it's been working as expected, but I'm running into a casting issue with nullable integers in a nested object on the 'id' property

```json
{
    "company_detail": null,
    "country_code": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "code": "1",
            "country_name": "United States (+1)"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "code": "1",
            "country_name": "Canada (+1)"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "code": "44",
            "country_name": "United Kingdom (+44)"
        }
    ]
}
```

The exception is thrown when reading a session variable from HttpContext or when deserializing manually

```
return _accessor.HttpContext.Session.Get<UserInformation>(SessionKeyNames.UserInformation);

 var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInformation>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new UserInformation
            {
                CountryCode = new List<CountryCode> { new CountryCode { Id = 1, Code = "1", CountryName = "United States"} }
            }));
```

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error setting value to 'Id' on 'Models.CountryCode'.'

InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'.
```

```
public class NullSafeJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => true;

    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType);
        bool asString = objectType == typeof(string);
        object obj = asString ? String.Empty : obj = contract.DefaultCreator();

        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Null:
            case JsonToken.None:
                break;
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                var arr = JArray.Load(reader);
                serializer.Populate(arr.CreateReader(), obj);
                break;
            case JsonToken.String:
                var nullish = String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)reader.Value) || Regex.IsMatch((string)reader.Value, @"^['""]?null['""]?$");
                obj =  (nullish && !asString) ? contract.DefaultCreator() : reader.Value;
                break;
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                var o = JObject.Load(reader);

                //obj = o.ToObject(objectType);
                serializer.Populate(o.CreateReader(), obj);
                break;
            default:
                obj = reader.Value;
                break;
        }
        return obj;

    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }     
}
```

The type that is throwing the exception is the 'CountryCode' property

```
public class UserInformation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Company detail.
    /// </summary>       
    public CompanyDetail CompanyDetail { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// country code list
    /// </summary>
    public List<CountryCode> CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class CountryCode
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int? Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "code")]
    public string Code
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "country_name")]
    public string CountryName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public CountryCode()
    {
    }

    public CountryCode(int? id = null, string code = null, string countryName = null)
    {
        Id = id;
        Code = code;
        CountryName = countryName;
    }
}
```

My startup file contains

```
public override void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    JsonConvert.DefaultSettings().Converters.Add(new NullSafeJsonConverter());
}
```

Note that, for nullable value types, the converter is probably not necessary.

Comment: Use long instead of int as it says in the exception.

Comment: I can't edit the class. This works fine without the custom converter so I'm just wondering what difference I'm missing

Comment: Can you explain what the converter is trying to accomplish?  Is the idea that whenever a token is a `null` value or a string with the value `"null"` a default instance of the incoming type should be allocated and returned?  If you could precisely specify your requirements we may be able to suggest better ways to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Is your code on the stack when the exception is thrown? If so, where? You may need to add code to your converter to handle numeric types.  What does the offending JSON look like (boiled down to a [mre])?

Comment: Agree with @Flydog57 we need to see a JSON sample which requires the converter, as explained in [ask].

Comment: @dbc  updated with intent, json sample, and exception location

Comment: @shoop - do you only want to do that for `null` JSON tokens, or do you really want to do that for `"null"` string-valued tokens as well?  Also, do you really need to do that for nullable value types like `int?`?

Comment: @dbc ```"null"``` string-valued tokens as well. For nullable value types, no it's probably not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is here:

```
obj = reader.Value;
```

You have no guarantee that the value in the reader is of the same type as the required `objectType`.  `JsonTextReader` parses integers as `long` and floating-point values as `double`, but `objectType` might be `int`, `decimal`, or even some enum type.  So you will need to deserialize or convert `reader.Value` to the required type.

The following version of the converter corrects this problem by calling `Convert.ChangeType()` for primitive types, and fixes a few other issues as well:

```
public class NullSafeJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => 
        Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) == null; // For nullable value types, no it's probably not necessary

    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //TODO: Handle enums serialized as strings.
        //TODO: Handle types with their own converters.
        //TODO: What happens of objectType has a parameterized creator?
        Debug.Assert(CanConvert(objectType)); // Assert no unsupported types.
        var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType);
        bool asString = objectType == typeof(string);
        object obj = asString ? String.Empty : obj = contract.DefaultCreator();// What happens if DefaultCreator() is null?

        //Skip comments via MoveToContentAndAssert():
        switch (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType)
        {
            // TODO
            case JsonToken.Null:
            case JsonToken.None:
                break;
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                //Loading into a temp JArray is not necessary.
                //var arr = JArray.Load(reader);
                //TODO: This won't work for arrays or read-only collections.
                serializer.Populate(reader, obj);
                break;
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                //Loading into a temp JObject is not necessary.
                //var o = JObject.Load(reader);
                //obj = o.ToObject(objectType);
                serializer.Populate(reader, obj);
                break;
            case JsonToken.String when asString:
                obj = reader.Value; // No need to do Regex.IsMatch() for strings.
                break;
            case JsonToken.String:
                var nullish = String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)reader.Value) || Regex.IsMatch((string)reader.Value, @"^['""]?null['""]?$");
                obj = nullish ? contract.DefaultCreator() : reader.Value;
                break;
            default:
                obj = reader.Value;
                break;
        }
        var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType;
        if (obj != null && obj.GetType() != underlyingType && (underlyingType.IsPrimitive || underlyingType.IsEnum))
            obj = Convert.ChangeType(obj, underlyingType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return obj;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }     
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader AssertTokenType(this JsonReader reader, JsonToken tokenType) => 
        reader.TokenType == tokenType ? reader : throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0}, expected {1}", reader.TokenType, tokenType));
    
    public static JsonReader ReadToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader) =>
        reader.ReadAndAssert().MoveToContentAndAssert();

    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(reader);
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(reader);
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

That being said, I see a few problems with this approach:

- Arrays and read-only collections cannot be deserialized, because they cannot be populated.
- Objects with no default creator cannot be deserialized, because they cannot be created.
- It is unclear how the converter should interact with types that their own converters, e.g. enums types or `DateTime`.
- The converter will supersede Newtonsoft's [built-in fallback converters](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/tree/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters) for types like `DataTable` and `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`.
- The converter maps `null` (and `"null"`) values to non-null defaults, but if a value is missing completely the corresponding property value may still be `null`.

However the specific problem in the question is resolved.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NU8QLw).

Comment: Certainly answered the question, and thank you for the other advice. Obviously some more to think about before adding this globally